# Retrieving value 'outside' a span class selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read the following value 9.692

```
 <li><span class="tab-box">Deposit:</span> 9.692</li>
```

I can't seem to be able to get text outside the span tag. I can retrieve the text deposit with the following:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='tab-box']")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text `9.692` is in the parent `<li>`. You can get the `<li>` tag with this `xpath`

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[.//span[@class='tab-box']]")
```

And remove the `<span>` text to get the result

```
deposit_text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="tab-box"]').text
all_text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[//span[@class="tab-box"]]').text
number_text = all_text.replace(deposit_text, '')
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Why is the "." required in .//?